# Taking $dx\to 0$ in expression to get PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Consider the expression
$$V-\left(V+\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} \,dx\right)+p(x,t)\,dx = m \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} \, dx$$

Now take the limit as $dx\to 0$ to obtain a PDE.

How can we obtain a PDE by taking $dx\to 0$? I only obtain $0=0$. Would appreciate some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $V$ cancels $-V$, so you are left with

$$-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}dx+p(x,t)dx = m\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}dx $$

which is an equality of $1$-forms and which leads immediately to

$$-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} +p(x,t) = m\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} .$$

Comment: But then, how is the limit of $dx\to 0$ involved, if we just cancel it out by division?

Comment: @sequence: In no way. That limit shouldn't even have been part of your question. Those limits are allowed only when they appear in fractions, such as $\frac {\Bbb d u} {\Bbb d x}$, where they lead to derivatives; otherwise, they are meaningless. Also, notice that your equation might not be exactly what you are after, because it is not clear who the unknown is: $V$ or $u$?